# Sealing Razor defined components

Tags: c#, razor, blazor

You can seal a class defined component like this:

```cs
public sealed class MyComponent 
{ 
   protected override void BuildRenderTree(RenderTreeBuilder builder)
   {
      // some RenderTreeBuilder Code
   }
}
```

But does this work?

```
// MyComponent.razor
Some Razor Markup
```

```cs
public sealed partial class MyComponent { }
```

The Razor compiled partial class isn't sealed.

Anyone know?

Comment: Thanks.  I was looking for a second opinion.  In theory sealing one of many partials should work.  As all the Razor compiler does is produce a partial class then it should all work.  Main reason for the question was I was looking for ways to seal components to get the small performance gains from sealed classes.